# SQL get additional results based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple sql table with 4 columns (dateSlot (varchar), timeSlot (varchar), slotOrder (int) and taken (bool)

I have data that looks like so:

```
<LCTimeSlots>
<dateSlot>Wednesday, September, 26th, 2018</dateSlot>
<id>1</id>
<slotOrder>1</slotOrder>
<taken>false</taken>
<timeSlot>4:00pm</timeSlot>
</LCTimeSlots>
<LCTimeSlots>
<dateSlot>Wednesday, September, 26th, 2018</dateSlot>
<id>2</id>
<slotOrder>2</slotOrder>
<taken>false</taken>
<timeSlot>5:00pm</timeSlot>
</LCTimeSlots>
<LCTimeSlots>
<dateSlot>Thursday, September, 27th, 2018</dateSlot>
<id>3</id>
<slotOrder>3</slotOrder>
<taken>false</taken>
<timeSlot>4:00pm</timeSlot>
</LCTimeSlots>
<LCTimeSlots>
<dateSlot>Thursday, September, 27th, 2018</dateSlot>
<id>4</id>
<slotOrder>4</slotOrder>
<taken>false</taken>
<timeSlot>5:00pm</timeSlot>
</LCTimeSlots>
```

and I getting this data like so:

```
SELECT id, dateSlot, timeSlot, slotOrder, taken FROM LCTimeSlots
```

What I am trying to do is write a condition that will only show the Wednesday, September, 26th, 2018 records and not show the Thursday, September, 27th, 2018 until all the Wednesday, September, 26th, 2018 records are marked as taken...Is what I am trying to do possible?

Comment: What database engine are you using? (SQL Server, MySQL), please add to your post tags.

Comment: SQL Server @RyanWilson....PS are you related to Russel Wilson? lol

Comment: Yeah, he's my cousin. J/K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest something like this (though it might not be exact syntax for SQL Server)

```
SELECT id, dateSlot, timeSlot, slotOrder, taken FROM LCTimeSlots WHERE dateSlot = 'Wednesday, September, 26th, 2018' 
UNION SELECT id, dateSlot, timeSlot, slotOrder, taken FROM LCTimeSlots WHERE dateSlot = 'Thursday, September, 27th, 2018' 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM FROM LCTimeSlots WHERE dateSlot = 'Wednesday, September, 26th, 2018' AND taken = false);
```